# Static pointer to dynamically allocated buffer inside function

Tags: c, numpy, malloc

I have a function in C that dynamically allocates a buffer, which is passed to another function to store its return value. Something like the following dummy example:

```
void other_function(float in, float *out, int out_len) {
    /* Fills 'out' with 'out_len' values calculated from 'in' */
}

void function(float *data, int data_len, float *out) {
    float *buf;
    int buf_len = 2 * data_len, i;
    buf = malloc(sizeof(float) * buf_len);

    for (i = 0; i < data_len; i++, data++, out++) {
        other_function(*data, buf, buf_len);
        /* Do some other stuff with the contents of buf and write to *out */
    }
    free buf;
}
```

`function` is called by an iterator over a multi-dimensional array (it's a NumPy gufunc kernel, to be precise), so it gets called millions of times with the same value for `data_len`. It seems wasteful to be creating and destroying the buffer over and over again. I would normally move allocation of the buffer to the function that calls `function`, and pass a poiinter to it, but I don't directly control that, so not possible. Instead, I am considering doing the following:

```
void function(float *data, int data_len, float *out) {
    static float *buf = NULL;
    static int buf_len = 0;
    int i;
    if (buf_len != 2 * data_len) {
        buf_len = 2 * data_len;
        buf = realloc(buf, sizeof(float) * buf_len); /* same as malloc if buf == NULL */
    }
    for (i = 0; i < data_len; i++, data++, out++) {
        other_function(*data, buf, buf_len);
        /* Do some other stuff with the contents of buf and write to *out */
    }
}
```

That means that I never directly free the memory I allocate: it gets reused in subsequent calls, and then lingers there until my program exits. It doesn't seem like the right thing to do, but not too bad either, as the amount of memory allocated is always going to be small. Am I over worrying? Is there a better approach to this?

Comment: Do you have any guarentees about the size of the dynamic buffer?

Comment: no raii in C, maybe the compiler you use has raii extensions like in gcc: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html

Comment: @JustinMeiners Yes, it is very tightly controlled. At most it would be 65536 items long, but that's rare, typically 16 or 32 items long.

Comment: I would use `<` rather than `!=` ... otherwise you're liable to still be doing many allocations. Better yet, use a VLA if you can (or alloca if you can get away with that).

Comment: I'm using MSVC, which I believe is strict C89, so no VLA I think...

Comment: @Jaime No VLA yet, but you have `alloca`, which is equivalent and very useful if you're not scared by decreased portability and ominous warnings - see updated answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This approach is legitimate (but see below), although tools like valgrind will flag it as a "leak". (It's not a leak functionally, as a true memory leak is *unbounded* increase in memory usage.) You might want to benchmark exactly how much time is lost on `malloc()` and `free()` compared to other things the function is doing.

If you can use C99 or gcc, and if your buffer is not overly large, you should also consider variable-length arrays, which are as fast (or faster than) a static buffer, and create no fragmentation. If you're on another compiler, you can look into the non-standard (but [widely](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/alloca.3.html) [supported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wb1s57t5.aspx)) `alloca()` extension.

You do need to be aware that using a static buffer makes your function:

1. Thread-unsafe - if it is called from multiple threads simultaneously, it will destroy the data of the other instance. If the Python is called from numpy, this is probably not a problem, as threads will be effectively serialized by the GIL.
2. Non-reentrant - if `other_function` calls some Python code which ends up calling `function` - for whatever reason - before `function` finishes, your function will again destroy its own data.

If you don't need true parallel execution and reentrancy, this use of `static` variables is fine, and a lot of C code uses them that way.

Comment: Good point on the thread-safety... If this ever gets parallelized it would be with `multiprocessing`. Will each process then get its own copy of the static variable?

Comment: @Jaime Yes - separate processes don't share global variables.

Answer (score 3):

This is a fine approach, and something like this is likely used internally by many libraries. The memory will be freed automatically when the program exits.

You might want to round `buf_len` up to a multiple of some block size, so you don't `realloc()` every time `data_len` changes a small bit. But if `data_len` is almost always the same size, this isn't necessary.